# Django Authenticate returns none if registered via a front-end registration form

Tags: python, django

I've searched everywhere for a solution to this problem. Yet, no resolution as of yet.

**The problem**
After successfully creating a user via a front-end registration form, upon logging in using a front-end login form, the "Authenticate" function returns "None".

The interesting part, if I am to create a new user via the admin panel (using similar code), I am then able to login via the front-end login form.

The custom user model I've created does use an email address as the Username. If a user registers using the front-end register form, the user details are saved to the database, where the password is properly hashed.

**Here is the code:**

## From Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from .models import User as CustomUser
from django.conf import settings


class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'full_name')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control loginInput', 'placeholder': 'Your Email (you@company.com)'})
        self.fields['full_name'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control loginInput', 'placeholder': 'Your Full Name'})
        self.fields['email'].label = ''
        self.fields['full_name'].label = ''
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control loginInput', 'placeholder': 'Your Password'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control loginInput', 'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'})

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        qs = CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("email is taken")
        return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Saving the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

## From Views.py

```
def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        registration = forms.RegisterForm(data=request.POST)

        if registration.is_valid():
            member = registration.save()
            member.set_password(member.password)
            member.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(registration.errors)

    else:
        registration = forms.RegisterForm()

    print("Registered: " + str(registered))
    return render(request, 'accounts/registration.html',
                  {'registration_form': registration,
                   'registered': registered,
                   })


def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account_index'))

            else:
                HttpResponse("ACCOUNT NOT ACTIVE")
        else:
            print("Someone tried to login and failed!")
            print("Email: {} and password {}".format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse("invalid login details supplied!")

    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/user_login.html', {})
```

I'm at a loss at the present time. Could use some direction or advice.

Comment: i think that the problem is in the registration view, replace this line "member = registration.save()" and put  that "member = registration.save(commit=False)"

Comment: Brian, thanks for your response. Changing the commit argument to False doesn't appear to resolve this problem. I certainly do appreciate your input on the matter. With that said, just to clearify, in the user_login view "user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)" seems to return "none". I'm guessing it might have something to do with the fact that I am using a custom user model. But I'm not 100% sure at this point.

Comment: Okay, why do not you use the django user model?

Comment: Brian, that's a great question! The default User model that Django provides simply won't allow me to accomplish the goals of the web app I'm building. Granted, Django provides some good user based functionality out of the box, but in this case, it won't suffice.

Comment: Can you explain why it's not enough? Generally, when you need more data in the user model, usually create a profile model related to the user, or a customized user model that inherits from the django user model.

Comment: In most cases, that approach would be appropriate. However, in my case it wouldn't. I would love to explain in detail why, however, It would be a rather long winded explanation. Again, I appreciate your input and feedback. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've resolved this issue. It seems as though I just needed to sleep on it.

Here is the code that was causing the issue:

## In Views.py

```
member.set_password(member.password)
```

It seems as if though it was setting a hashed version of the password. But "set_password" must be the raw version of the password.

**To fix this I changed it to:**

```
member.set_password(request.POST.get('password1'))
```

Behold, it works!

Comment: Jaja ok, it's alright, i don´t remember it! ... great, you have answered yourself